# How to query array to retrieve value from key, MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Say I have the following document in my MongoDB collection, how can I retrieve the values of the keys in `fixtures` so that if I use a limit of `1` only get the first object in `fixtures` and if I limit it to `2` it get both in the first document and the one in the second document.

The output I'm looking for is a pipeline that returns the key, value pairs from a array, like `fixtures` in the form of a dict.

```py
#Example
collection.find({}, {'fixtures':1, '_id': 0}).limit(1)
>>>{'fixtures': [{'away_team': 'Arsenal',
              'away_team_id': 1,
              'away_team_score': 1,
              'away_team_shortName': 'Arsenal',
              'home_team': 'Newcastle United',
              'home_team_id': 23,
              'home_team_score': 0,
              'home_team_shortName': 'Newcastle',
             }]}

#The output I want
>>>{'away_team': 'Arsenal',
   'away_team_id': 1,
   'away_team_score': 1,
   'away_team_shortName': 'Arsenal',
   'home_team': 'Newcastle United',
   'home_team_id': 23,
   'home_team_score': 0,
   'home_team_shortName': 'Newcastle',
}
```

How can this be archived with either `find()` or `aggregate()`. I know about `find({}, {'fixtures.KEY': 1})` but it returns the following datastructure that is hard to work with:
`fixtures:[{KEY: value}]`

```py
    {
        "team": "Arsenal",
        "team_id": 1,
        "team_shortName": "Arsenal",
        "competition": "Premier League",
        "competition_abbr": "EN_PR",
        "competition_id": 1,
        "season_label": "2019/20",
        "season_id": 274,
        "fixtures": [
            {
                "home_team": "Brighton and Hove Albion",
                "home_team_id": 131,
                "home_team_shortName": "Brighton",
                "home_team_score": 2,
                "away_team": "Arsenal",
                "away_team_id": 1,
                "away_team_shortName": "Arsenal",
                "away_team_score": 1,
            },
            {
                "home_team": "Manchester City",
                "home_team_id": 11,
                "home_team_shortName": "Man City",
                "home_team_score": 3,
                "away_team": "Arsenal",
                "away_team_id": 1,
                "away_team_shortName": "Arsenal",
                "away_team_score": 0,
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "team": "Arsenal",
        "team_id": 1,
        "team_shortName": "Arsenal",
        "competition": "Premier League",
        "competition_abbr": "EN_PR",
        "competition_id": 1,
        "season_label": "2019/20",
        "season_id": 274,
        "fixtures": [
            {
                "home_team": "Arsenal",
                "home_team_id": 1,
                "home_team_shortName": "Arsenal",
                "home_team_score": 3,
                "away_team": "Everton",
                "away_team_id": 7,
                "away_team_shortName": "Everton",
                "away_team_score": 2,
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: It's still not quite clear to me how the output should look like, could you include an example output as well?

Comment: @thammada.ts thank you for the input, is it clearer now?

Comment: So you want the first element of the array field `fixtures` as the root document of the result? Or element at array index X, where you can specify X?

Comment: @thammada.ts Sorry for the confusion, I updated expected output for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation pipeline with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/), with the following syntax

`{ $arrayElemAt: [ <array>, <idx> ] }`

Along with [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/), to place the result at the top level

`{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: <replacementDocument> } }`

```
collection.aggregate([{
  $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayElemAt: ['$fixtures', 0] } } // get the first element as a top level document
}, {
  $limit: 1 // to limit just 1 document, or omit the stage to get all documents
}])
```

Comment: Thank you for the patience, this was exactly what I was looking for! If you don't mind me asking, when using this aggregation, is it possible to select top level keys simultaneously say `season_label ` ?

Comment: You will have to use `$mergeObjects` before to merge the result of `$arrayElemAt` with an object with desired key

Comment: I see, thank you for the valuable insights and for taking your time!

Comment: Feel free ask if you have tried and still need help with `$mergeObjects`

Comment: I tried the following `{"$mergeObjects":[{"$match" : { "season_label" : "$season_label" }}, {Your aggregation $replaceRoot...}, {"$limit": 2}]`. The response I got was this `$mergeObjects is not allowed in this atlas tier`

Comment: I might have misunderstood your requirement. Do you want to match `season_label` with a certain value before getting fixtures, or do you want to get the parent field `season_label` included in the output?

Comment: Sorry for making it unclear, want to get the parent field `season_label` included in the output!

Comment: that would be `... newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [{ season_label, "$season_label" }, { $arrayElemAt: ... }] }`

Comment: I noticed that the aggregation pipeline that `$arrayElemAt` only returns the object that gets indexed. How would one go about if I wanted all the objects in the array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216624/discussion-between-thammada-ts-and-misterbutter).